# The speed of 'extract(year from sysdate)'

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries:

```
with tmp as (
select asy.aim_student_id, ast.aim_test, asq.response
  from aim_student_test ast
  join aim_student_qst asq on (asq.aps_yr = ast.aps_yr and asq.aim_test = ast.aim_test and asq.aim_id = ast.aim_id)
  join aim_student_yr asy on (asy.aps_yr = ast.aps_yr and asy.aim_student_yr_id = ast.aim_student_yr_id)
    where asq.aps_yr = '2012'
    and asq.qst_num = 1)
select aim_student_id, aim_test, response  
  from tmp
  where response is null
  -- execution-time: 0.032 seconds


define this_year = extract(year from sysdate)
with tmp as (
select asy.aim_student_id, ast.aim_test, asq.response
  from aim_student_test ast
  join aim_student_qst asq on (asq.aps_yr = ast.aps_yr and asq.aim_test = ast.aim_test and asq.aim_id = ast.aim_id)
  join aim_student_yr asy on (asy.aps_yr = ast.aps_yr and asy.aim_student_yr_id = ast.aim_student_yr_id)
    where asq.aps_yr = &this_year
    and asq.qst_num = 1)
select aim_student_id, aim_test, response  
  from tmp
  where response is null
  -- execution-time: 82.202 seconds
```

The only difference is that in one I use '2012' and the other I implement extract(year from sysdate).

I can only imagine that Oracle is computing extract(year from sysdate) for EVERY record it checks, and that I just can't figure out how to make it compute this once and use it as a variable. Searching has not returned me the answers I seek... so I come to the magicians of SO.com. HOW do I properly use

```
extract(year from sysdate)
```

as a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `&this_year` in the query causes a substitution of the *string* `extract(year from sysdate)`, so the second query actually has:

```
where asq.aps_yr = extract(year from sysdate)
```

which you can see from the second explain plan. That in itself probably isn't the problem; what's possibly slowing it down is that doing this is changing the plan from an `index range scan` to an `index skip scan` against `aim_student_qstp1`. The real difference is that in the fast version you're comparing `asq.aps_yr` to a string (`'2012'`), in the second it's a number (`2012`), and - as also shown in the explain plan - this is causing it to do `to_number(asq.aps_yr)` which is stopping the index being used as you expect.

You could fix this in your code by making it:

```
where asq.aps_yr = to_char(&this_year)
```

If you want to calculate it once before the query runs and then use it as a variable, there are at least two ways (in SQL*Plus/SQL Developer). Sticking with substitution variables you can use the [`column`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm) commands instead of the `define`:

```
column tmp_this_year new_value this_year
set termout off
select extract(year from sysdate) as tmp_this_year from dual;
set termout on
set verify off
```

... which makes `&this_year=2012` (the `termout` changes just make the actual retrieval invisible, and the `verify` stops it telling you when it uses the substitution; both so you don't get extra output in your script), and change your query to have:

```
where asq.aps_yr = '&this_year'
```

... so the value is treated as a string, making a `to_char()` unnecessary.

Or you can use bind variables:

```
var this_year varchar2(4);
set feedback off;
exec :this_year := extract(year from sysdate);
```

... and then your query has:

```
where asq.aps_yr = :this_year
```

Note that in this case you don't need the quotes because the bind variable is defined as a string already - there's an implicit conversion in the `exec` that sets it.

Comment: Hey mate - sorry I didn't post on this sooner - I work part-time. Today is my first day back this week and this was the first thing I tried. It worked like a charm and was ***exactly*** what I was looking for - I have therefore marked this as my accepted answer, as the other one was helpful but did not completely cover what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the difference is due to extracting the year from the date.  I'm pretty sure Oracle would only be extracting the year once, since it is using a variable in the second case.

The difference is due to the execution path used by the query.  You would need to post the execution plans to really see the difference.  Using an explicit constant gives the optimizer more information for choosing an optimal query plan.

For instance, if the data is partitioned by year, then with a constant year, Oracle can determine which partition has the data.  In the second case, Oracle might not recognize the value as a constant, and require reading all data partitions.  This is just an example of what might happen -- I'm not sure what Oracle does in this case.

Comment: Wow, checking the plan is fascinating and whilst it hasn't solved my problem yet it is exactly the type of thing I am trying to learn (tools that are useful for a long time). Thankyou. [Fast Plan](http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/4052/fastplan.png) vs [Slow Plan](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/3623/slowplan.png)

You were right, clearly there is a MASSIVE difference between the two. Now my question is... how do I go from here to sorting out the problem?

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is how do I supply extract(year from sysdate) to Oracle as a CONSTANT. Before it starts optimising its query.

We could just use '2012' but this query and many others I am creating will be used here for several years to come. I finish work here at the end of this year, and if I can create these queries to always work without creating additional work - that would be awesome. Plus it is very interesting to learn

Comment: Please ask another question and include the query plans, table structure, and sizing.  You have a very specific question about performance, but you asked a very general question.

Comment: Ok I'll do that - before I go though:

table structure - does this mean how each of the linked tables is structured?

sizing - does this mean the size of the tables?

Comment: @nebffa Before you ask another question, you may want to read about bind variable peeking, adaptive cursor sharing, histograms, and cardinality feedback.  There can be a big difference between using a variable and using a literal.